Categorification of "sub" in monoidal category
As we know, we have monoid objects (or ring objects) in monoidal categories. For example, the monoid objects in $\mathrm{Vect}\; k$ are $k-$algebras.
I want to question that can we define a "subring object" to categorification the notion of "subalgebra"?
It seems hard to have the notion "sub" in categories. And I searched the term "relative category", but it is a little hard to understand and seems to have no relation to us.

The most common notion of subobject in algebra is isomorphism classes of monomorphisms. Have you tried looking at subobjects in the category of monoids on $k\mathrm{Vect}$, for example?

That's an answer, not a comment.

It's a question, in fact.

The OP asked for a formalization of sub-xyz in categories. Your link answers it.

@NaïmFavier: Thanks a lot. The way to look at subobjects in the category of monoids really helps.
